# Easiest way to check if string is URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

The goal is to check if a string is a URL, no regex needed.

I have a form that lets users upload an image or add an image from a URL.

I get:

`van_gogh_shoes.jpg`

or

`http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2YNtlcmDDBpseEqUkMhe7-netq7RL2u_bw3_34VwB-Tsv2V-B`

Users can add just 1 image, either uploaded or URL. So in mysql I'm updating the same column named `entry_image` with one of the values above.

When displaying images I need to check in the simplest way possible if the value from `entry_image` column is a URL. If so, display the full URL otherwise my own path to the uploaded image.

```
<img src="<?php (filter_var($row->entry_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? $row->entry_image : "uploads/entries/{$row->user_id}/{$row->entry_image} ?>">
```

I'm using `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` which seems to work but as with most things I didn't use before I'm not sure if it's the best solution.. What are your thoughts?

I'm trying to avoid regex or other heavy validation codes when displaying images because I'm already validating the values when entering data to mysql. Please share a simpler solution if it exists.

Comment: 1 what wrong with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL 2 how does the user enters url if he is required to enter a full path like http://...... you can check if string has  http://

Comment: @COLDTOLD the URL is not required if the user doesn't enter it. I'm handling all other URL validation on form submission. For displaying images checking if it's an URL is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter_var()` is the best solution for this. Thumbs up for not wanting a regex as a solution.

Other than that, I just want to point out that transferring the image file from an external URL to your server is a better way (in my opinion). It will keep you from problems like deleted external images, and connection issues with external servers. You won't also have to worry about validating URLs. This is just a suggestion though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I'm considering to upload URL images as soon as I learn how.